# CircleAvatar show image out of the circle in actual shape

Tags: flutter, dart

CircleAvatar show the image out of the circle and backgroundimage in CircleAvatar do not work with ImageFile

```
CircleAvatar(
        radius: 54,
        child: Image.file(state.image),
      );
    }
```

Comment: I think you should add your images into an asset and then call them in `backgroundImage  CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/IMG_0153.jpeg'),
              )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use `CircleAvatar` `backgroundImage` property. If you need to use image from some file, you can provide it using `FileImage` class. For example:

```
 CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 54,
                  backgroundImage: FileImage(state.image),
                ),
```

### Result:

[image]